# The headers set inside nginx don't appear in $_SERVER variable of PHP, but appear in Laravel request() function

Tags: php, laravel, docker, nginx

There is a Laravel application on Docker. It has php-fpm and nginx containers. When I post an HTTP request from the nginx to an external server, the external server identifies the IP address of the client as the IP of the nginx container not the IP address of the host.

To solve the issue, I want to add a custom header to nginx container that determines the IP of the address like this

```
add_header X-SERVER-REAL-IP "1.2.3.4";
```

in `default.conf` file. Then in the backend application, I check the following

```
if(isset($_SERVER['X-SERVER-REAL-IP']))
{
    $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = $_SERVER['X-SERVER-REAL-IP'];
}
```

The problem is, that the super global variable `$_SERVER` does not have the key `X-SERVER-REAL-IP` while the `request()` function in the controller of the Laravel application, has this key and it surprises me. Now my question is :

1. Whether I am doing a best practice to set the real IP address of the server?
2. > why `$_SERVER` has not the `X-SERVER-REAL-IP` key while `request()` function of Laravel has?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you dump the $_SERVER variable, what keys do you have ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [PHP documentation for `$_SERVER`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) says:

> In addition to the elements listed below, PHP will create additional elements with values from request headers. These entries will be named `HTTP_` followed by the header name, capitalized and with underscores instead of hyphens. For example, the `Accept-Language` header would be available as `$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']`.

Which means that `X-SERVER-REAL-IP` would become `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_SERVER_REAL_IP']`. But if you're working with a framework like Laravel that has it's own way of accessing headers and other request data, it is generally a good idea to use that instead of using lower-level PHP ways like `$_SERVER`.

However, note that [`add_header`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html#add_header) in the Nginx config won't do what you expect here, as it adds response headers and those are not visible to PHP code processing the request. Passing data from Nginx to the PHP code depends on how you're running PHP, for example with PHP-FPM via Nginx's `mod_fastcgi` you can use [`fastcgi_param`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#fastcgi_param) to pass data to `$_SERVER` directly.

Comment: Thanks, it was a good point but still doesn't work. I set `add_header X-SERVER-REAL-IP "1.2.3.4";` and `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_SERVER_REAL_IP']` is still null

Comment: The nginx [add_header](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html#add_header) directive adds a response header, it won't be visible to whatever is processing the request. Passing data from the Nginx configuration to PHP depends on how you're invoking PHP, e.g. with PHP-FPM/FastCGI you could use [fastcgi_param](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#fastcgi_param).

Comment: I can't use the `request()` file because I need to set the `REMOTE_ADDR` in a position where `$request()` is inaccessible

Comment: the `fastcgi ` solution worked. plz include in answer to accept

Comment: Edited the answer to include that.